# Is it considered bad practice to use hidden elements which are displayed on "small devices" only?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, html-table

I'm using a table to display information about users registered in the system. I would like to make this table more "user friendly" when displayed on small (mobile) devices.

Here it is:

```
 <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>User ID</td>
        <td>Role</td>
        <td>Group</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Dummy User ID 1</td>
        <td>Dummy User Role 1</td>
        <td>Dummy User Group 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dummy User ID 2</td>
        <td>Dummy User Role 2</td>
        <td>Dummy User Group 2</td>
    </tr>
    ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm using media queries to change table's appearance on small devices.

First of all, I'm hiding thead.

Secondly, I'm applying to td elements "display: block;" to show them one under another.

And thirdly, I decided to display column name next to the User ID / Role / Group values:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>User ID</td>
        <td>Role</td>
        <td>Group</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>User ID:</span> Dummy User ID 1
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>User Role:</span> Dummy User Role 1
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>User Group:</span> Dummy User Group 1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>User ID:</span> Dummy User ID 2
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>User Role:</span> Dummy User Role 2
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>User Group:</span> Dummy User Group 2
        </td>
    </tr>
    ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So these span elements are displayed only on small devices. On medium / big devices "display: none;" is applied to them, but they still exist in the HTML markup. Is it considered as a bad practice to have invisible HTML elements like these? Or maybe there is another better solution?

Comment: If your code works but you are trying to get someone to review it for improvements, post at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This is a question not about the code itself. But about the "practice" used in this code snippet. The code is provided only as an example to make my question more clear. I can remove it if necessary.

Comment: So you want someone's recommendation about if this is a best practice or not?

Comment: Yes. I want to know if using hidden elements which are displayed only for some type of devices is a bad practice. And if it is what approach is usually used instead.

Comment: That is what CodeReview is for not what stackoverflow

Comment: Okay. My bad then. I just thought that CodeReview is designed for reviewing the code instead of giving answers for general questions.

Comment: Actually, @scrappedcola is wrong here. Code Review is for reviewing **Actual code** (which may include reviewing if it follows best practices), but example/pseudo code is strictly Off-Topic

Comment: @scrappedcola no it's not. Per CR's help center, asking "what's the best practice regarding X?" is explicitly off-topic. Please read [a guide to CR for SO users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777/23788) on CR meta.

Comment: To be honest I can't understand why this question is related to the CodeReview since it is not connected to specific peace of code. I provided code example just to make my question more clear. However, the example can be replaced with any other or removed from question completely and doesn't really need any kind of review. I can assume I'm wrong and would like to find out if I am, but in my opinion here's not the best place for this discussion.

Comment: @Mat'sMug thanks i'll take a look at that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is necessarily a terrible practice, but if having those DOM elements hidden in the screen display has you bent out of shape, I have an alternative solution. Seeing as the contents of the spans are consistent, why not add them to the small device CSS as 'before' pseudo-elements?

Something like:

```
td:nth-child(1)::before { content: "User ID: "; }
td:nth-child(2)::before { content: "User Role: "; }
td:nth-child(3)::before { content: "User Group: "; }
```

That way, you keep you screen display's DOM nice and neat, and add in the extra label text for mobile only, as needed, via CSS.